# addEventListener issue creating To Do list with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My project is requiring the following:

> For this assignment you will be combining your knowledge of DOM access
> and events to build a todo app! As a user, you should be able to:
>
> Add a new todo (by submitting a form)
>
> Mark a todo as completed (cross out the text of the todo)
>
> Remove a todo

The only issue I am running into with my code is the complete button. When clicked it should just cross out the text (which it does), however the completed and remove buttons disappear. I am fine to have the completed button disappear, however the remove button should stay. Why do these buttons disappear? Is my removeBtn.addEventListener coded incorrectly? Do I have to create a new removebutton within this addEventListener?

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
  const newToDoName = document.createElement('span');
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  const completeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newToDoName.innerText = input.value;
  removeBtn.innerText = 'Click to Remove';
  completeBtn.innerText = 'Click if Completed';
  newToDo.appendChild(newToDoName);
  newToDo.appendChild(completeBtn);
  newToDo.appendChild(removeBtn);
  input.value = '';
  todolist.appendChild(newToDo);

  completeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    newToDo.innerHTML = newToDoName.innerText.strike();
  })

  removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To Do List:</h1>
  <ul id="todolist">
  </ul>
  <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
    <input type="text" id="theToDo" name="addToDo" placeholder="Add to the list here">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src=TodoList.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
  const newToDoName = document.createElement('span');
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  const completeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newToDoName.innerText = input.value;
  removeBtn.innerText = 'Click to Remove';
  completeBtn.innerText = 'Click if Completed';
  newToDo.appendChild(newToDoName);
  newToDo.appendChild(completeBtn);
  newToDo.appendChild(removeBtn);
  input.value = '';
  todolist.appendChild(newToDo);

  completeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    newToDo.innerHTML = newToDoName.innerText.strike();
    newToDo.appendChild(removeBtn);
  })

  removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To Do List:</h1>
  <ul id="todolist">
  </ul>
  <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
    <input type="text" id="theToDo" name="addToDo" placeholder="Add to the list here">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src=TodoList.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`innerHTML` remove all content between the tag.